# Ruby on Rails - Order records by created_at and sort_by by boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I'm trying to loop over my `posts` and `order('created_at DESC')` and `sort` by `pinned` *(which is a `boolean`)*.

How is it possible to `order` records by `created_at` and `sort` with **pinned** so **pinned** posts come on top.

I've tried with the following, but the sorting gets massed up and is no longer ordered by `created_at` or if I try to add the `sort_by` at the end, the `pagination` would stop work.

```
posts = Post.active.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(25)
@posts = posts.sort_by { |post| [post.pinned ? 0 : 1, post] }
```

I have also tried the following with no luck:

```
@posts = Post.active.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(25)
// In my view
- @posts.sort_by { |post| [post.pinned ? 0 : 1, post] }.each do |post|
```

This will produce an error for the pagination

```
posts = Post.active.order('created_at DESC').sort_by { |post| [post.pinned ? 0 : 1, post] }.page(params[:page]).per(25)
```

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: You don't want to use `sort_by` . Instead order the rows by the boolean column. Something like `.order('CASE WHEN pinned THEN 1 ELSE 0 END', 'created_at DESC')`.

Comment: In general you should remember that databases are really good at sorting data efficiently. Pulling that data out of the database and reordering it in Ruby should really just be a last resort as its extremely unefficient. Especially if you where to pull everything out of the table and then "paginate" it by only using the first 25 elements of an array with thousands of elements.

Comment: Thanks @max I tried with the following `@posts = Post.active.order('CASE WHEN pinned THEN 1 ELSE 0 END', 'created_at DESC')` and it gives `Query method called with non-attribute argument(s): "CASE WHEN pinned THEN 1 ELSE 0 END"` error

Comment: appreciate your help @max `sqlite` in dev and `pg` in production. I tested with both and still the same error on both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Max's answer is the way to go, the only thing missing in his comment was wrapping it in Arel.sql

```
posts = Post.active.order(Arel.sql("CASE WHEN pinned THEN 0 ELSE 1 END"), "created_at DESC"))
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you can construct the query with `Arel::Nodes::Case` instead of a string:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  def self.pinned_on_top
    kase = Arel::Nodes::Case.new(arel_table[:pinned])
    order(
      kase.when(1).then(0).else(1)
    )
  end
end
```

```
# Given the following
Post.create(pinned: true)   # id: 1
Post.create(pinned: false)  # id: 2
Post.create(pinned: true)   # id: 3

Post.pinned_on_top.order(created_at: :desc).ids # 3, 1, 2
```

The key advantage is portability.